# Find any type of url, and replace "click here" text with regexp jquery

Tags: jquery, url

I need a little script in jQ because I have to change the long urls to a shorten "click here" text. I want to change only the url text not the value of href's attrib like this:

```
<a href="http://verylongurl.ext/ohshitwhatlongisit/yaythatstoolongforme">http://verylongurl.ext/ohshitwhatlongisit/yaythatstoolongforme</a>
```

to..

```
<a href="http://verylongurl.ext/ohshitwhatlongisit/yaythatstoolongforme">click here</a>
```

The script must work on any possible type of url for example: http: https: ftp: and so on...

tyvm girls and guys!

Regs!

Comment: So you want to replace the text in all of the links? Or only for specific ones? Or only where the text is a URL?

Comment: To be clear: this is for any anchor whose `href` is the exact same as its text?

Comment: all of the links, but only the url relater... so I don't want to change other links link {a href="http://otherlink.ext"}read this{/a}

Comment: I really don't understand why you want to use regexp to replace the text since you just want to replace the text on "any type of url".

So if you only want to change the text on any link this should do it: 

    $('a').text('click here');

Comment: @nolabel: because i dont want to change the linked texts...
{a href="otherlink.ext";}read this{/a}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following searches for links whose text starts with `XXXX://` where X is any number of non-whitespace characters and replaces the text with 'Click here':

```
$('a').each(function(i,elem){
    $this = $(elem);
    text = $this.html();
    if (text.search(/\S*:\/\//) == 0) {
        $this.html('Click here');
    }
});
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/cs59n/2/)

---

Or, as Felix mentions below, a shorter way to write this would be:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
                return $(this).text().search(/\S*:\/\//) == 0;
              })
      .text('Click here');
```

Comment: This is it:) You are the man:)) Sorry but the regexp is hard to me:) Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf('://') > -1;
}).text('Click here');
```

If we can assume that `://` is only contained in URLs and not in other text, this will work. No regular expression needed.

Reference: [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
jQuery("a").text("click here");
```

Comment: no.. it's too easy:D i need the find + regexp and the change script (like yours)